# fopen() return NULL and errno is 0

Tags: c, file, null, fopen, errno

I tried to create a file (src), read read characters from it and copy them to another file (dst), when the name of the files I'm getting from the command line arguments but the fopen() function return NULL.
I read here that i should use errno.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
void copyFile(char *src, char *dst);

int main(int args, char **argv) {
    int option = args;

    if(option == 3){
       copyFile(argv[1], argv[2]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void copyFile(char *src, char *dst) {
    FILE *srcFile = fopen(src, "rb");
    FILE *dstFile = fopen(dst, "wb");

    if (srcFile || dstFile) {
        printf("Error %d \n", errno);
        return;
    } else {
        char buff[2];
        while (fread(buff, 2, 1, srcFile) != 0) {
            fwrite(buff, 2, 1, dstFile);
        }
        fclose(srcFile);
        fclose(dstFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are testing for `fopen` failure wrong. The line `if (srcFile || dstFile) {` will return true if *either* `srcFile` or `dstFile` is **not NULL**.

What you need to test for is if either of them *are* NULL:

`if(srcFile==NULL || dstFile==NULL)`

Personally, I'd split this into consecutive `if` statements so that you can output a more detailed error about which file failed to open, not just "at least one file failed to open".

Comment: This is not the only problem - if the first `fopen` fails but the second succeeds, the second will set `errno` to zero to indicate success, so there needs to be `if(!fopen(src)) print(errno); if(!fopen(dst)) print(errno);` in order to catch the `errno` codes correctly.